# If $(u,v)$ is a point on $4x^2+a^2y^2=4a^2$,where $4<a^2<8$,that is farthest from $(0,-2)$ then $u+v$ is equal to?

Tags: derivatives

If $(u,v)$ is a point on $4x^2+a^2y^2=4a^2$,where $4<a^2<8$,that is farthest from $(0,-2)$ then $u+v$ is equal to?

My Approach:

I took a parametric point $(t,4-4t^2/a^2)$.And then tried to find the minima of the distance.But that is too lengthy method.Any other suggestions?

Comment: Random thought -- don't know if it is useful --- use Lagrangian since there are more variables -- will give you some good equations. On the other hand, it is an ellipse, so that might help

Comment: Langrangian :-P what's that?

Comment: You know what I meant. Sorry for the typo. Cpiegore has used that in his answer

Comment: @Shailesh no I really don't know that...I'm in high school just(India)...I was looking for some other method...anyway thanks for the suggestion...

Comment: I believe you are studying for JEE. So it will help if you look that up on your own

Answer (score 2):

Use the method of Lagrange multipliers.  In your problem you will get a system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns:
$2x=8xt$

$2y+4=2a^2yt$

$4x^2+a^2y^2=4a^2$

Solving you get

$t = 1/4$

x = $a^2\sqrt(a^2-8)\frac{1}{a^2-4}$

y = $\frac{8}{a^2-4}$

Comment: I dont know lagrange multipliers....anyway thanks for the effort...

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

WLOG any point on the ellipse $$(a\cos t,2\sin t)$$

So, if the distance is $d,$

$$d^2=(a\cos t)^2+(2+2\sin t)^2=8+4\sin t+(a^2-4)\cos^2t$$
$$=8+\sqrt{4^2+(a^2-4)^2}\sin\left(t+\arccos\dfrac4{\sqrt{4^2+(a^2-4)^2}}\right)$$

$$\le8+\sqrt{4^2+(a^2-4)^2}$$

Now $4<a^2<8,0<a^2-4<4\implies(a^2-4)^2\le4^2$

So, the maximum value i.e., the equality occurs if $t+\arccos\dfrac4{\sqrt{4^2+(a^2-4)^2}}=2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2\iff t=2m\pi+\arcsin\dfrac4{\sqrt{4^2+(a^2-4)^2}}$

and $a^2-8$ is maximum which can be made arbitrarily small but will remain negative.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(0,-2)$.

If $P(x,y)$ is a point on $4x^2+a^2y^2=4a^2$, then
$$\begin{align}AP^2&=x^2+(y+2)^2
\\\\&=a^2-\frac{a^2y^2}{4}+(y+2)^2
\\\\&=\underbrace{\frac{4-a^2}{4}}_{\text{negative}}\bigg(y-\frac{8}{a^2-4}\bigg)^2+\frac{a^4}{a^2-4}\end{align}$$

Let $f(y):=\frac{4-a^2}{4}\bigg(y-\frac{8}{a^2-4}\bigg)^2+\frac{a^4}{a^2-4}$.

Then, $Y=f(y)$ is a downward parabola with $(\text{axis of symmetry})=\frac{8}{a^2-4}\gt 2$.

Since $y\le 2$, considering the graph of $Y=f(y)$, we get
$$AP^2=f(y)\le f(2)=16$$
The equality is attained only when $(x,y)=(0,2)$.

Therefore, we get $(u,v)=(0,2)$, and so $$\color{red}{u+v=2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Provided $4x^2+a^2y^2=4a^2$, we have to maximize $$x^2+(y+2)^2=a^2-a^2y^2/4+(y+2)^2=f(y).$$ Since the range of $y$ is $[-2,2]$ and $$f'(y)=(2-a^2/2)y+4\ge$$ $$(2-a^2/2)\cdot 2+4=8-a^2>0,$$ the function $f$ is increasing on the provided range and so $f$ attains its maximum at $y=2$. Then $x=0$ and so $u+v=x+y=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet an other solution, that tries to work geometrically as much as possible. If computations are started, then only for a specific geometric issue, and they should be of low algebraic level. Well, i am also needing a continuity argument.

---

The given constraint connecting $x,y$, $4x^2+a^2y^2=4a^2y^2$, is the ellipse of equation (divide by the R.H.S.)
$$
(E)\ :\qquad
\left(\frac xa\right)^2 +\left(\frac y2\right)^2 = 1\ .
$$
We search a/the point $(u,v)$ on $(E)$ which is at maximal distance from the given point $P(0, -2)$. It turns out that this point is $Q(0, 2)$.
Let us show this. The distance between $P$ and $Q$ is $PQ=4$. Is it the maximal distance? Before we start to answer the question, it may be useful to "see" how the problem is "working". Here is a special case with $a$ almost equal to $3$, and it is left open if the condition $a\le 2\sqrt 2$ is satisfied:

[image: mse question 1638315 circle and ellipse]

In red we have the ellipse $(E)$, and its point $P=(0,-2)$. Using radius four, we draw the circle centered in $P$ with radius $PQ=4$. Both the circle and the ellipse are tangent in $Q$ to the horizontal line $y=2$ through $Q$.
How is the problem moving, when sliding the position of $(\pm a,0)$? We expect for $a=2$ that the ellipse becomes a circle centered in the origin, thus completely "inside" the other circle, then making $a$ bigger and bigger the ellipse will have the "upper" part getting closer and closer to the horizontal line $y=2$ through $Q$, so at some point it may also go "beyond" the limits of the disk... When does this happen? So we have a geometrical question.

---

**Is the ellipse completely inside the (closed interior disk of) the circle?**

If yes, then the maximal value is taken in $Q=(0,2)$, the sum of the components of $Q$ is $0+2=2$ (and has no sense in the given geometric, or optimization context, but is a way of published examination problems to give the answer without giving it), and we are done.

If not, *reductio ad absurdum*, let us assume this, then consider the difference function of the two continuous functions on $[-a, a]$ determined by the two graphs in the upper half plane, the one for the circle, minus the one for the ellipse. By assumption, the difference is $0$ in $0$, takes also positive values, and in $\pm a$ we have a negative value. So the difference also takes a further zero value in $(0,a)$ and/or $(-a,0)$ (by symmetry). So the circle and the ellipse intersect in a further point. Let us intersect the two curves, see if this is possible:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x^2 + (y+2)^2 &= 4^2\ ,\\
x^2 +\frac 14 a^2y ^2 &= a^2\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
We eliminate $x$ by subtracting the equations, we obtain one equation in $y$ with parameter $a$, which is in its simpler form:
$$
(a^2-4)y^2 - 16y + 4(12-a^2)=0\ .
$$
The case $a=2$ is easily considered geometrically, $(E)$ is a circle, and it is contained in the (closed) interior disk of the other circle. So assume $a>2$, making the above equation an equation of degree two. One solution is $y=2$ (since it was also in the initial equation), and the other one is (Vieta for the product of the roots) such that $y+2=\frac {16}{a^2-4}$. We insert in the first equation to get the value of $x$, which satisfies:
$$
x^2 = 4^2 -(y+2)^2 = 4^2 -\frac{16^2}{(a^2-4)^2}
=\frac{4^2}{(a^2-4)^2}((a^2-4)^2-4^2)
=\frac{4^2}{(a^2-4)^2}a^2(a^2-8)\le 0\ .
$$
In the only case where there is a real $x$ solution, we have $a^2-8=0$, thus $x=0$, and the corresponding point is again $Q$. Contradiction. Our assumption is false. This leads to the wanted conclusion.

$\square$

---

*Note:* The above computation explains also why in case of $a^2-8\ge 0$ we have a further intersection of the two conics, and the maximal distance is taken elsewhere. We have to draw further concentric circles centered in $P=(-2,0)$, and see which one in the family is touching the ellipse.